# High Speed compression for raw data in language C

Tags: algorithm, performance, compression

I need to compress raw unknown data <= 4MB to smaller (the size is not important here). The most important part is the speed of the compression. 
I need to keep datas as data. I can't make a file or zip it.

Which algorithm of compression will you recommend me ?

For example : 
My raw data (4MB) are send by ethernet in approximately 58ms.
I want to improve this sending. 
I use language C to program it. 
Unfortunately i use a CPU with a 600MHz of cadence.

I already try the LZ4 library. It compress the data in 65ms. 
Is there a better algorithm ? Of more simple, is it possible to improve my speed ?

Comment: Could you describe your data?

Comment: Maybe you have multiple cores and can compress alternate frames on different cores using multithreading.

Comment: If you look here https://facebook.github.io/zstd/ and here https://github.com/lz4/lz4 LZ4 as at the top when it comes to comression speed. I would say this CPU sucks to much (or you didn't turn on all possible optimizations).

Comment: There is little sense to discuss compression while we know nothing about data  nature. For example, the simplest RLE is extremely fast for cartoon-like pictures

Comment: Thank's for yours answers. the fact is my data could be stack on different cache memory. if it's the same type of data like int data it will be on the same memory space. I totaly agree with you Anty, my CPU sucks to much .. But I need to use it. I can't change it. My data are raw variables, I could be an int or a strucurt, board of string.. I need to do redundancy of calculation. I send all information by ethernet to a second machine. @MBo

Comment: If your data contain strings or another repeating patterns, then dictionary methods like LZ is good choice. Perhaps you could dump typical data on PC and try different compression methods to find the fastest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LZ4 library proposes an [acceleration parameter](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/v1.8.3/lib/lz4.h#L171) which can be used to tune speed / compression trade off, and make compression as fast as you like.

Comment: you write, I already used this function. I try to compress 4MB. I began with a simple way : 4 MB of int tables. those tables were empty. So the compression was easy ! at the end the compression was 66ms and the transfer of raw data 57ms... so it was not conclusive

Comment: 1. did you increased the acceleration parameter ? 2. What speed is `memcpy()` on your system ?